# Content management system for Android App

Tags: android, content-management-system

I've recently started programming my first android app in eclipse using java and xml and I'm relatively new to both languages.

My App will contain mostly static information for students in university which I plan to simply save as text in the xml itself but the clients wish to have a few pages on the app with content that they will be able to change regularly without having to look at or understand any code.

Basically what I'm looking to do is have a basic content management system that can only be accessed by the client and they can use it easily enough to change the content of those specific pages.

Any help would be great on this thanks!

Comment: How did you go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If the information allows it you could integrate it inside a webview that the clients can update through an web content management system.

Answer (score 0):

You need a web server from where you can send the updated info as push notifications.